# Google Play Services Ads

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a problem with the component `Google Play Services Ads`, once added to the project after compiling I get these errors:

> APT0000 error: No resource found That matches the given name (at
>   'fair' value with '@integer/google_play_services_version'). APT0000
>   error: No resource found That matches the given name (at 'theme' value
>   with '@style/Theme.IAPTheme').

Even the sample project supplied by the same mistake.

Can someone help me?

Thank you
Stefano

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Stefano. Please provide the code you tried, or, more precisely, a minimal code (and instructions) to reproduce your issue (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others can help you. Best regards.

Comment: Is not necessary any code. I have the latest version of xamarin for visual studio. I create a simple android app and I add google play services ads from components gallery. At this moment it's impossibile to compile project with the above errors.

Comment: One will hardly help you without a possibility to reproduce the issue, sorry.